# Is there some issue doing it in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do it without worry about performance problems?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

(function(new_selector) { new_selector('.classname').fadeIn('fast'); })($);

});
```

or

```
$(function() {

(function(new_selector) { new_selector('.classname').fadeIn('fast'); })($);

});
```

thanks.

maybe it could be a idiot question but i like to worry about performance.

Comment: Do you mean if there is any difference in performance between `$(function() {})` and `$(document).ready(function() {})`?

Comment: no, i mean about using (function(new_selector) { new_selector('.classname').fadeIn('fast'); })($);
 inside ready event.

Comment: cuz i'm setting a new jQuery selector name, i want to know if is there some performance problem.

Comment: @RubensStock It's merely a new name for the same object. There is **no performance difference**.

Answer (score 4):

Performance speaking, there is **no** (notable?) difference.

If you pass a function, it will simply be proxied to `.ready()` method.

If you worry about performance, try to avoid `.class` selector.

Comment: BTW, why `.class` selector is bad?

Comment: Your code is run 1 time for a page load.  Even if it was a slight delay between the calls it wouldn't matter.  Boris has the correct answer.

Comment: .class is just the most general, that is why it is slower performance-wise; has to scan everything in the DOM as any element can have a class.

Comment: @VisioN, it is not "bad", it is just much slower than using id or context. It is slow because it is needed to loop over all the DOM, when an ID can be directly accessed. In most case you can speed up things by providing a context `$('.class', '#id');` (this will "fragment" DOM and loop only over the given context (it can be an ID  or previously selected element)

Comment: @BorisGuéry Well, from that sense we could advice the OP to avoid using jQuery ;)

Comment: @VisioN, not at all, you will have similar behavior with the native `document.getElementsByClassName()`, it will be faster if you do `document.getElementById('ID').getElementsByClassName('class')`